# Using PHP sessions in jQuery/HTML/Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, session

After a successful login attempt my php script starts a session like this:

```
    session_set_cookie_params(1800,'/','www.mydomain.com',true);
    session_start();
    header("location:mainpage.html");
```

Now my questions are:

- How can I save my user-id to my session for further use?
- Would it be sufficient to add these 3 code snippet to keep my sessions alive in a jQuery Mobile page:

mysession.php:

```
     <?php
     session_set_cookie_params(1800,'/','www.mydomain.com',true);
     session_start();
     ?>
```

somewhere in mainpage.html:

```
    function getHttpRequestObj()
    {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            return new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
            return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    }

    function callSession(id)
    {
    var xmlhttp = getHttpRequestObj();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","mysession.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

And then in the outmost div (name='main') in mainpage.html

```
      $(document).ready(function() {
callSession('main');
});
```

Comment: session_register **This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.**

Comment: That helps. Then I would need a new method of somehow storing my user-id in my session for further use and validation.

So basically I am now only using the session_set_cookie_params and session_start part with only the direct header to mainpage.html as long as the MySQL query is authenticated and login information is correct.

Comment: you only need session_start() than then just use the $_SESSION global array

Comment: So a UID is automatically created for me? I still need to use the username to get the userid from MySQL though, unless I've overseen something.

Comment: session_set_cookie_params(1800,'/','www.mydomain.com',true);
    session_start(); $_SESSION['id'] == $userid;
    header("location:mainpage.html");     - A tad hard to read but I think that'll do as far as saving my userid from MySQL goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved by adding the following code at the top of my mainpage.html and renaming it to mainpage.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
?>
```

Now I can access my userid from anywhere by doing

```
<? echo $id ?>
```

Comment: or you could just do echo $_SESSION['id'] ?